# Replace the name of the cities with "City"

Tags: asp.net

I am retrieving data from SQL Server to a grid view in ASP.Net. Below is the header of the grid view after I retrieved the data from the database.

```
Time| Atlanta_1| Atlanta_2| Atlanta_3|
```

I want to replace the name of the cities with "City" dynamically e.g.

```
Time| City_1| City_2| City_3|
```

So basically I want to replace a part of the header with "City" and I want to do it while binding it in a grid view NOT in SQL Server. Below is the code how I am retrieving data from the database to my gridview

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("My Connection");

string s = "My Stored Procedure";

con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(s, con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds);

gridView1.DataSource = ds;
gridView1.DataBind();

con.Close();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Are you talking about the GridView HeaderText and AutoGenerated columns?

Comment: Yes I am talking about the GridView HeaderText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the RowDataBound event. Then loop all the Header Cells. Check the Cell for the `_` and replace with the correct value. If it is always `Atlanta` you can just do a Replace.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.Text.Contains("_"))
            {
                cell.Text = "City_" + cell.Text.Split('_')[1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```